# Como Pasar la conexion de un Socket a otro JFrame?

Tags: java, netbeans, socket

estoy creando una aplicación cliente/servidor, inicio mi primera conexión al servidor desde un jFrame (LogIn), ahora quiero que esa mima conexión pase a otro JFrame (PaginaPrincipal) para así no tener que cerrar la conexion y luego tener que abrir una nueva. es posible ? o como podría implementar esto... es que mi aplicación se basa en que un usuario acceda al sistema atravez de un formulario de login y luego pasa a la pagina principal donde hace consultas a una base de datos.

Comment: Puedes hacer que la conexion se pueda acceder desde cualquier lugar con static.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.